# How do I retrieve data from cell of selected row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` with 7 columns, column 0 and 1 are not visible.  Column 0 is the ID column.  When I select a `row` I would like to get the value in `Column 0`.  Once I have the value, I can then delete the row from the `data table`.  Deleting the row from the `DataGridView` is not a problem.

This line returns the `row index` with no problem;

```
int rowIndex = customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

Then with all my research it would appear that this line would get the `data from column 0` of the selected `row`.  But it does not.  I get an error that states "When converting a string to DateTime, Parse the string to take the date before......"

```
int contact_ID = int.Parse(customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView[0, rowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Any help with teaching me how to get the `value of a column` `toString` from the selected row of a `DataGridView` would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Coeur, thanks for fixing my spelling

Answer (score 0):

I have found my answer in another post [Get value in specific column in DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834844/get-value-in-specific-column-in-datagridview).  I am not sure why I didn't find this last night except that today I simplified my search and came across this post.  Sorry for any trouble I may have caused, I really do like using this site for help.

```
DataGridViewRow row = customer_Ship_ContactsDataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningRow;

string contact_ID = row.Cells["Contact_ID"].Value.ToString();
```